# Rails api cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I want to caching api responses like

```
sitename.com/posts.json
```

for example for 5 minutes, where I must configure Rails and maybe what external tools I must use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
 caches_page :posts, :expires_in => 5.minutes
```

it's explained decently on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#page-caching

Notice that `expires_in` only works with memcached as the cache store, AFAIK.